# Unable to understand certain git behaviour

Tags: git, gitlab

I am not able to understand certain behaviour exhibited by git.

I have a local branch, say myBranch, which is in sync with remote branch on gitlab by same name. Infact, I had first created the branch locally, and then pushed it to remote using:

> git push -u origin myBranch

I understand it also means that origin/myBranch is also at same commit, say C1,  as myBranch(I hope I am correct here).

Now I make some local changes and then add them using amend.

> git commit --amend --no-edit.

So I am amending existing commit C1, and I expect both myBranch and origin/myBranch should point to C1.

But when I do git status, I get:

> On branch myBranch
>
> Your branch and 'origin/myBranch' have diverged,
>   and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
>     (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Why should I get this when both myBranch and origin/myBranch are pointing to C1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a commit to your local branch does not automatically update the remote tracking branch. In order to update the remote tracking branch with any additional commits in the local branch, use `git push` (assuming that you set up the remote tracking branch already, which you did when specifying `-u` for the initial `git push`).

As an aside, in generate you should avoid amending commits on branches that you've pushed to a remote repository. When you amend a commit, it changes the commit object to include whatever changes you're amending. If you try to push this branch using `git push`, you'll get an error saying the push was rejected because the tip of your branch is behind its remote counterpart.

The reason for that is that Git uses cryptographic SHA-1 hashes to uniquely identify every commit (you can see them in the commit history, for example by executing `git log`), and some of the commit metadata such as message and timestamp are also being hashed along with the commit's contents. Essentially, when you amended that commit you created a new commit, with a different hash, and replaced the old one with it. Thus, your local branch is pointing to that commit and is behind the remote because it doesn't contain the old one, and the remote branch is behind your local branch because it doesn't contain the new one.

You'll need to force push (`git push -f`) in order to push your changes to the remote repository - replacing the commit the remote branch points to with the new one as well. The problem with that is if any other developer has pulled that branch to their local machine, it is very hard for them to sync their changes since you changed the branch out from under them.

Amending commits and rebasing is fine for local or private branches, but in general you should avoid doing this for any branch that another developer could have pulled down to their machine.

Comment: But I made amend to C1. So myBranch is still at C1, just like origin/myBranch. So they shouldn't diverge, isn't?

Comment: @Mandroid When you amend a commit, you change its hash. The has is what git uses to uniquely identify a commit. If a commit has a different hash, it's a different commit as far as git is concerned. So when you amended C1, it is no longer C1 - now it is C1`.

Answer (score 2):

The `--amend` option seems like it changes an existing commit. **This is not the case.**

I think the best illustration here is to **draw (part of) the commit graph**.  Remember that in Git, each commit has a unique hash ID—a big ugly string of letters and numbers.  Every commit has its own separate ID.  These things are too unwieldy for humans to use regularly, so we tend to use *names*, such as branch names, to remember them:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- myBranch
```

When you make a new commit, you do it by first doing a `git checkout` of the desired branch.  This attaches the special name `HEAD` to that branch name, *and* extracts the specific commit—in this case `H`—to which the name points.

You then make whatever changes you want (in your work-tree), use `git add` (to copy the updated files back into the index / staging-area), and run `git commit` (without `--amend`).  At this point, Git:

- saves the index / staging-area files as the new snapshot for the new commit;
- sets the new commit's author and committer to you, and its date-and-time-stamps to "now";
- writes your log message to the new commit, and
- writes the *raw hash ID* of the *current* commit (for which we're using the letter `H`) into the new commit as its parent.

So now we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- myBranch (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

where `I` is the new commit.  The last step is the tricky part: your Git now writes the *new commit's hash ID* (which was just created by creating the commit—we're calling it `I` here but again it's some big ugly hash ID) into the name `myBranch`, as that's the one that the special name `HEAD` is attached to:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- myBranch (HEAD)
```

If you now `git push` this to the other Git that you are calling `origin`, your Git remembers that their Git's `myBranch` is pointing to commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- myBranch (HEAD), origin/myBranch
```

But now you decide that there's something wrong with commit `I`.  So you make some changes to files and `git add` them, and run `git commit --amend`.  **This does not change commit `I`.**  Instead, it creates another new commit—let's call it `J`—but this time, instead of setting `J`'s parent to `I`, Git sets `J`'s parent to `H` again.  Then it writes `J`'s actual hash ID, whatever that is, into `myBranch`:

```
             J   <-- myBranch (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- origin/myBranch
```

This is what is in your repository.  The other repository, over at `origin`, has its `myBranch` name pointing to commit `I`—the one you gave it earlier.

You must now correct the other Git repository's idea of where its `myBranch` should point.  You must deliver commit `J` to it, then tell it: *forget commit `I`, just make your `myBranch` name commit `J`.*  Once you do that, both your repository *and* their repository will no longer have a way to find commit `I` at all.  Your Git will have this:

```
             J   <-- myBranch (HEAD), origin/myBranch
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   [abandoned]
```

Note that commit `I` is not yet *gone*.  It will stick around for a while—at least 30 days by default—in case you decide that you would like it back.  It will, however, be hard to *find*.  I've used `I` to stand in for its actual hash ID.  But what *is* its actual hash ID?  How will you ever guess what its hash ID might be?  (There is a way, but save that for another question :-) )

As [Andy said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58032470/1256452), you will need to use `git push -f` to force the server to forget commit `I` while remembering new replacement commit `J`.  This is fine as long as everyone who might use the server's `myBranch` name agrees in advance that these names are manipulated this way.  If you're the only one using the server repository, you must agree with yourself that this is OK.  If other people are using it, make sure they understand what you're doing first!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Explained a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am amending existing commit C1, and I expect both myBranch and origin/myBranch should point to C1.

You've edited a commit at branch `C1` and `git` moved the branch to the new commit. There is no reason to expect `git` would move another branch, local or remote-tracking.

The reference `origin/myBranch` (it's not exactly a branch, it's a reference) stays at the old commit because the remote-tracking reference only moves when you fetch/pull/push. The very idea of the remote-tracking references is to remember where their upstream remote branches were when you communicated with the remote repository.

Comment: But I made amend, so myBranch is still at C1,and origin/myBranch too is at C1. So they shouldn't diverge. Isn't?

Comment: No. Amend created a new commit. Commit modifications in `git` are never done in place. Every commit editing creates a new commit with a different SHA1 ID. Old commits stay in the database unreferenced until garbage collector removes them.